# use of DZNPhotoPickerController in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, swift, flickr

I am trying to use DZNPhotoPickerController library in swift, this library seems very useful and it let's your app simply search photos from services like flickrr 500px and google photos, this library can be found here: [DZNPhotoPickerController](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNPhotoPickerController)

when I import it into my Swift project I get plenty of errors about missing libraries and frameWorks and imports but it seems that this library is completed and specified with no errors. it asks me about Kiwi and pods or XCTests and other things I don't really know about them, so if some one can please download this library into a swift project and please tell me what should I do in order to make it work I would be really thankful. or maybe some of you are familiar with other open source libraries of images web searching and cropping images circular it will be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to get started with Cocoapods, in case you haven't yet. It's a powerful tool which does all the import and dependency stuff for you.. and it works great with DZNPhotoPickerController (and Swift). Here is a tutorial by RayWenderlich which might help you to get started: http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2 (it's not up-to-date but still very useful). Of course, you'll also find a lot of information in the official CocoaPods docs (https://guides.cocoapods.org).

For your Swift project with DZNPhotoPickerController, you should use a Podfile like:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'DZNPhotoPickerController'
```